# How to access .java files from a directory outside of a package in android-studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I try to solve this problem for hours now and didn't find a solution on the internet.
my project looks like this:

[image: project]
I want to access the files in the marked directory in the `de.MayerhoferSimon.Vertretungsplan` package. (yes, I know packages should be lowercase.)

Is this possible and when yes, how?

I tried some things with the dependencies in the .gradle file of the `:app` module but nothing worked.

Comment: A Java package cannot have that name. They should be folders, e.g. `de/MayerhoferSimon/Vertretungsplan` (you can check the `com` folder to see what I'm talking about). Then add the `de` folder as source code in the project settings.

Comment: the problem is: this directory is a library and I added it as a git submodule

Comment: Then it should be packed as a JAR or a separate module and linked in the classpath.

Comment: @m0skit0 the package `de.MayerhoferSimon.Vertretungsplan` is allright. the linter error is just because of the other files.

Comment: it is not a android project neither a android module. it's a simple library

Comment: Yes I know. That's what I'm talking about. It's better to put it in a JAR or on a separate module and link on classpath instead of copying in the current module. Anyway, if you mark the folder as a source code folder in the project settings, it should work.

Comment: with `android{  ...  sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java/libs/webuntisaccessor/WebUntisAccessor/src'
    }
}` it worked :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should create a library module for your webuntisaccessor code instead of putting this in the libs folder.

```
root
  settings.gradle
  app
    build.gradle
  webuntisaccessor
    src
      main    
        java
    build.gradle
```

In `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':webuntisaccessor' , ':app'
```

In   `webuntisaccessor/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

In   `app/build.gradle` add:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':webuntisaccessor')
}
```