# How to change the default location for the main folder in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a project with the default structure:

`c:\repo\my-project\app\src\main\java`, `cpp`, `assets`, etc.

I would like to leave the project at `c:\repo\my-project\app` but move the `src` folder to `c:\repo\somewhere-else\src`.

Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

### **No, unless you create another `build.gradle` file for C:/repo.**

You would also have to run `repo/build.gradle` and not the `build.gradle` files of the subfolders. Then you would use `sourceSets` to change the path of the `src` folder, and then you would manually move the folder.

I don't really see why you should change the defaults, but that *really* is a bad idea.

EDIT: See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681353/how-to-access-java-files-from-a-directory-outside-of-a-package-in-android-studi) for more information.

Comment: We have two different repos that share code. One for a compatibility library and one for the business logic. They're all linked into the same project right now and we need to oextract out the library code so another application can use it. I can create an aar but it would be a lot less work if I could just move the java and point the compiler to the new place. We're on a time crunch and the projects will both be ending soon, so "less work" > "better way."

Comment: See my edit. It will show you how to create a library module.